# Making a confusion matrix with numbers in each box

Tags: machine-learning, confusion-matrix

I tried to plot a confusion matrix with the below code, but i could not show the numbers in each box!

This is what i have done:

```
plt.matshow(cm, cmap= 'binary') #cubehelix, viridis, jet, PuOr, rainbow, RdBu
plt.title('Confusion matrix')
plt.colorbar()
plt.ylabel('True label')
plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I found the answer somewhere else.
Here is the link:   
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the [answer](https://www.kaggle.com/grfiv4/plot-a-confusion-matrix) on kaggle.

You only need to plug in your numbers from this code for example:

## Making the confusion matrix to describe the performance of a classifier

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix (y_test, y_pred2)

print (cm)
```